How to efficiently process messages from Rabbit MQ?
I have an architecture-related question about implementing a Python API/Microservices that need to process 30 million incoming requests.
I am planning to to use RabbitMQ or Amazon SQS.
Question: Question: Will the callback mechanism be able to handle the message volume efficiently, or do you have any better suggestions, please advice?

30 million incoming requests at the same time ?

both of these can handle millions of requests, however, the devil is in the detail (configuration, system resources etc). provide more detail and you may get a more detailled response

The requests per day

that number is well within the basic capabilities of either across day. Suggest you/your-team build a test harness that maps to your expected architecture to try out the behaviour of both wrt loading and response times. Have not used SQS, have previously used rabbitMQ in a high throughput app (with occasional bursts of 100's per second across a typical business day).

Very valuable suggestion, thank you

@ticktalk  What is the efficient way to implement the message processing/Message Consumption in a distributed environment - I think the listening the queue will not a right option.
